# How to use an SVG to make a hole in a <View /> (React Native)

Tags: css, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

I have made an orange View

[image: Orange bar]

And I want to use an SVG to carve out a hole out of the view (I'm rendering the curve in blue with `react-native-svg`)

[image: Orange bar with blue curve overlapping]

How can I "carve" a hole out of that View? Should I instead make the View an Svg?
If so, I like having the orange bar as a View instead of an Svg so it's borders don't stretch on different resolutions, it just becomes longer. Is there an Svg way of doing that responsivity  easily?

Comment: Have you tried using ``background-clip: content;`` or maybe another ``background-clip`` property work?

Comment: @ItzHex `background-clip` doesn't exist in React Native, but this has led me to `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` which might help. This issue https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view/issues/147 is quite discouraging, though.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm not the most experienced with react native, but I have faced this issue in other things where ``background-clip`` is a thing.